# Using axvspan for date ranges

Tags: python, date, matplotlib, time-series

I want to plot some time series that vary by season, and use axvspan to shade the part of the plot in winter time a different shade than the part in summer. I'm using [pyplot.plot_date](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date.html). My y values are an np array of floats, my x values are an np array of datetime objects converted using

```
    datetime.strptime(date, '%m-%d-%Y').
```

I want to use [pyplot.axvspan](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvspan.html) to apply the shades, but it seems to only work with regular numbers for the x axis, whereas my x axis are dates. The error I am running into is

```
    ValueError: view limit minimum -36858.05 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units
```

Any way to work around this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In matplotlib datetime axes also use numbers, [namely](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib-date-format)

> Matplotlib represents dates using floating point numbers specifying the number of days since 0001-01-01 UTC, plus 1.

Many functions like `plot`, `scatter`, `bar` etc. automatically convert `datetime` objects to those numbers, whereas many helper functions, like `axvspan`, did not do this automatic conversion until recent versions of matplotlib.

So in matplotlib 3 you can easily do

```
ax.axvspan(datetime(2019,3,1), datetime(2019,3,31))
```

but if using an older versionyou need to do it manually, using `matplotlib.dates.date2num`, e.g.

```
ax.axvspan(date2num(datetime(2019,3,1)), date2num(datetime(2019,3,31)))
```

Some complete example:

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import date2num

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot([datetime(2019,2,14), datetime(2019,4,26)], [1,2])

ax.axvspan(date2num(datetime(2019,3,1)), date2num(datetime(2019,3,31)), 
           label="March", color="crimson", alpha=0.3)

ax.legend()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help ImportanceOfBeingErnest, for any one reading this is how I made a plot with winter/summer backgrounds and single labels:

```
yearlist = ['2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
for i in range(len(yearlist)):
    if yearlist[i] == '2013':
        ax.axvspan(date2num(datetime.datetime(2012,10,15)), date2num(datetime.datetime(int(yearlist[i]),5,15)), 
           label="winter (15 october - 15 may)", color="crimson", alpha=0.3)
        ax.axvspan(date2num(datetime.datetime(int(yearlist[i]),5,15)), date2num(datetime.datetime(int(yearlist[i]),10,15)), 
           label="summer (15 may - 15 october)", color="blue", alpha=0.3)
    else:
        ax.axvspan(date2num(datetime.datetime(int(yearlist[i-1]),10,15)), date2num(datetime.datetime(int(yearlist[i]),5,15))
           , color="crimson", alpha=0.3)
        ax.axvspan(date2num(datetime.datetime(int(yearlist[i]),5,15)), date2num(datetime.datetime(int(yearlist[i]),10,15)), 
            color="blue", alpha=0.3)
```

[image]